# How do I remove the "..." at end of UILabel when resizing text to fit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am looking to autosize the text and display it all on one line. My problem is I don't want the "..." appended at the end of my text. How can I get rid of this? My first image is where it shows the "..." that I want to get rid of. The second image shows what happens when I change the numberOfLines on the cityLabel from 0 to 1. I also don't want this because I don't want multiple lines (just all on one line).

Here is the code:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (20, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 90)];
UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 55)];
UILabel *supportedCitiesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 65, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20)];

cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50.0];
cityLabel.text = @"Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas";
supportedCitiesLabel.text = @"Valley Test";


CGRect labelRect = cityLabel.frame;
cityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
cityLabel.numberOfLines = 1;


CGFloat fontSize = 50;
while(fontSize > 0.0)
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

    CGSize size = [cityLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000)
                                                                options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                             attributes:attrDict context:nil].size;

    if(size.height <= labelRect.size.height)
        break;

    fontSize -= 1.0;
}

cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
```

Image 1...
[image: Image 1]

Image 2...
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

Set `[UILabel lineBreakMode]`.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSParagraphStyle/lineBreakMode):

> **Constants**
>
> `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`
>
> Wrapping occurs at word
>   boundaries, unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line. See
>   Characters and Grapheme Clusters in String Programming Guide for a
>   discussion of issues related to determining word boundaries.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`
>
> Wrapping
>   occurs before the first character that doesn’t fit.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> `NSLineBreakByClipping`
>
> Lines are simply
>   not drawn past the edge of the text container.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> `NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead`
>
> The line
>   is displayed so that the end fits in the container and the missing
>   text at the beginning of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph.
>   Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for
>   single line text.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`
>
> The line
>   is displayed so that the beginning fits in the container and the
>   missing text at the end of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph.
>   Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for
>   single line text.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle`
>
> The line
>   is displayed so that the beginning and end fit in the container and
>   the missing text in the middle is indicated by an ellipsis glyph.
>   Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for
>   single line text.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

if you want text to autosize to fit width, why did you set `cityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;` I think it should be set to YES.

Then set `cityLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the flowing.

```
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 90)];
UILabel *cityLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 55)];
UILabel *supportedCitiesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (10, 65, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20)];

cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:50.0];
cityLabel.text = @"Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas Dallas";
supportedCitiesLabel.text = @"Valley Test";


CGRect labelRect = cityLabel.frame;
cityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
cityLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
cityLabel.numberOfLines = 1;


CGFloat fontSize = 50;
while(fontSize > 0.0)
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

    CGSize size = [cityLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes:attrDict context:nil].size;

    if(size.height <= labelRect.size.height)
        break;

    fontSize -= 1.0;
}

cityLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];


// [self.view addSubview:view];
// [view addSubview:cityLabel];
// [view addSubview:supportedCitiesLabel];
```

Comment: //note: add line
    cityLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    //update line
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting options here but this can all be done inside of Interface Builder with one setting:

[image]

1. Select the label
2. Under the Attributes Inspector select Minimum Font Scale under the Autoshrink option.
3. Choose an appropriate scale.

Also, if you have the correct AutoLayout constraints this should work dynamically.